# tmux detach pauses process

Tags: ssh, tmux, aws

My server stops processing requests as soon as I detach from the tmux session that runs my RESTful API. How can I prevent this?

I'm following the steps on this answer:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session

The server responds to requests when I first create the session and run the process, then stops when I detach and close SSH, then responds again when I connect back to SSH and attach to the previous session.

System details:

SSH connection to an Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (AWS EC2 instance) running a simple Python Flask application with Gunicorn and Nginx.

Comment: Have you encountered this again and found a cure? I've just experienced same thing with running Ray instance, very weird.